# My A-Frame component can't get current a-videosphere Y rotation

Tags: javascript, aframe

I would like to create a compass UI element to show the user where they are looking within a-videosphere.

To achieve this I need go get the Y rotation of the a-videosphere. I've created a component to read the Y rotation of my video sphere and (for the minute) update the console.

Here is my page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="play-on-window-click.js"></script>
        <script src="rotation-reader.js"></script>
        <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" loading-screen="enabled: false">

          <a-videosphere rotation="0 180 0" src="#video" 
                 play-on-window-click
                 rotation-reader>
          </a-videosphere> 

          <a-assets>
            <video id="video" style="display:none" 
           autoplay loop crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline webkit-playsinline>
    <source type="video/mp4"             src="https://ucarecdn.com/fadab25d-0b3a-45f7-8ef5-85318e92a261/" /></video>
          </a-assets>
        </a-scene>
        <!-- Show the rotation -->
        <div id="rotationDisplay" style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;color:white;border: 1px solid; padding:5px">-Dummy Text-</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Below is my component "rotation-reader.js-". I've attached it to the

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('rotation-reader', {
        tick: (function () {
            var rotation = this.el.components.rotation.data.y;
            console.log(rotation);
            })
    });
```

When I move around in the video, I expect that I'll get a print out of the Y rotation of the Videosphere, instead I get the initial Y rotation position of "160". This value doesn't seem to update :(

Here is a DEMO of it all: https://glitch.com/~veil-ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a little misconception here. You're rotating the camera, not the videosphere.

The videospheres rotation is constant, and set to `180` here:

```
<a-videosphere rotation="0 180 0" src="#video"
```

You should check the rotation of the camera, for example:

```
<a-camera rotation-reader>
```

Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/zxbfhn41/7/) fiddle.